# Cannot use yarn ENOENT README

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

When running yarn (or any yarn command e.g yarn install) I receive the following error:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/my.user/README'".
```

In the yarn error log there is nothing special except the same trace as above.

Yarn version:
**1.22.10**

Node version:
**14.7.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I deleted the README file in the above mentioned path of the trace. (Even if the trace said it does not exist, it existed).
Afterwards everything worked fine again.